# Fast way to place list elements on 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two lists, both lists of lists, called positions and values. Each sublist of positions and values contains the positions and values of peaks in a 2D array at times k=1,..,n. For example

```
values    = [[5,1,1,8,10],[3,1,7,9,4]]
positions = [[(0,0),(1,2),(1,4),(3,3),(4,4)],[(0,1),(1,3),(2,4),(3,4),(4,0)]]
```

Here, the list [5,1,1,8,10] are the values on a 2D array and [(0,0),(1,2),(1,4),(3,3),(4,4)] are the corresponding positions of those values at time 0 . Similarly, [3,1,7,9,4] are the values on a 2D array and [(0,1),(1,3),(2,4),(3,4),(4,0)] are the corresponding positions of those values at time 1. I want to put these values in their corresponding positions on a 2D array of zeros. So I made the following function

```
import itertools

def list_to_array(n_1, n_2, positions, values):

    new_array_list = []

    for k in range(len(positions)):

        A = np.zeros((n_1,n_2))

        for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_1), range(n_2)):

            if (i,j) in positions[k]:

                X = positions[k].index((i,j))
                A[i,j] = values[k][X]

        new_array_list += [A]

    return new_array_list
```

This should return two arrays

```
A[0] = [[  5.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   1.   0.   1.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.  10.]]

A[1] = [[ 0.  3.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  7.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  9.]
 [ 4.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

For a 256x256 array, a single iteration takes roughly one second and I need to perform the iteration for 1600 lists, which is long but still reasonable. However, I was also hoping to do this for larger arrays (up to 8x the length in each direction), so it is obvious the above code would just take too long. I was wondering if anyone knows of a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a specialist library. In this case, NumPy offers a vectorised solution.

For larger numeric data structures, a list-of-list approach is inefficient as it will use collections of pointers. Instead, NumPy utilizes contiguous memory blocks to enable efficient numerical transformations.

```
import numpy as np

values    = [[5,1,1,8,10],[3,1,7,9,4]]
positions = [[(0,0),(1,2),(1,4),(3,3),(4,4)],[(0,1),(1,3),(2,4),(3,4),(4,0)]]

# convert to NumPy arrays of shapes (10,) and (10, 2)      
val = np.array(values).flatten()
pos = np.array(positions).reshape(-1, 2)

# initialize array of zeros
arr = np.zeros(pos.max(0)+1)

# assign values to positions
arr[[*pos.T]] = val

print(arr)

array([[  5.,   3.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   7.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   8.,   9.],
       [  4.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  10.]])
```

---

If, as per your update, you require 2 separate arrays, you can repeat the process:

```
# convert to NumPy arrays of shapes (10,) and (10, 2)      
val1, val2 = (np.array(v).flatten() for v in values)
pos1, pos2 = (np.array(p).reshape(-1, 2) for p in positions)

# initialize array of zeros
arr1 = np.zeros(pos1.max(0)+1)
arr2 = np.zeros(pos2.max(0)+1)

# assign values to positions
arr1[[*pos1.T]] = val1
arr2[[*pos2.T]] = val2
```

Comment: Mate, sorry if my question wasn't clear. Each sub list of values and positions represents data at different times. Each sub list of values and positions _needs to be on it's own 2D array_, not on the same one. So [5,1,1,8,10] needs to be put on the first 2D array in the corresponding positions, and [3,1,7,9,4] needs to be on another 2D array in the corresponding positions. Any idea how to modify your code to do this? I'll also try it myself.

Comment: @Mattos, Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50983773/edit) with your *desired output* given your input?

Comment: @Mattos, See update, this is a trivial extension. You should also be able to create a function to perform this dynamically, i.e. for any number of arrays.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll still perform the loop to construct arr[k] and val[k] for k=1,..,1600, but change to flattening and reshaping which is inherently faster than doing the loop 'for i, j in itertools.product...'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mattos, Yes, I suspect these operations will be optimized using NumPy. But you should test with your data.

Comment: I actually have another question to ask on stack overflow, is there anyway I can ping you to it once I have written it?

Comment: Sure, add a comment on any of my posts with a link to your question.

Comment: I'll add a comment here when I've posted the question. Thanks heaps mate, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
def list_to_array(n_1, n_2, positions, values):

    new_array_list = []

    for k in range(len(positions)):

        A = np.zeros((n_1,n_2))

        for i in range(len(positions[k])):
            A[positions[k][i]] = values[k][i]
        new_array_list += [A]

    return new_array_list

values    = [[5,1,1,8,10],[3,1,7,9,4]]
positions = [[(0,0),(1,2),(1,4),(3,3),(4,4)],[(0,1),(1,3),(2,4),(3,4),(4,0)]]

print list_to_array(5,5,positions,values)
```

Comment: That is ridiculously faster than my code. Mine took ~800 seconds for 800 lists, yours took ~0.3 seconds. I don't know why I didn't think of this myself. Much appreciated (+1).

Comment: Your welcome. Suggestion for future. Whenever writing an algorithm, try to think about its space and time complexity in Big O terms and then try to reduce it if you can. It really helps.

Comment: Yeah I'll try your suggestion in the future. I knew mine would take a very long time because it was checking to see if each cell in a 256x256 array matched a tuple in my list and the code did this for all 800 sublists. I just didn't think about appending the values directly into the array (I don't know why). Thanks again.